# Freeing runtime created components with Delphi

Tags: delphi

In my app, I have a `TFDmemTable` that has a field named `"Panel"` that keeps the address of a runtime created `TPanel` with this statement:

`fieldByName('Panel').AsInteger := integer(TPanel.Create(nil))` (or `self`).

In the Table's `beforeClose` event, I try to destroy the `TPanel`, but the app falls in an ednless loop. The code is as below:

```pascal
procedure TDataForm.PicturesBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
var RE : TRichEdit;
    IM : TImage;
begin
    with Pictures do begin // Pictures is the Table
        first; // here goes again and again after "freeAndNil" statement
        while not EOF do begin
            try
               freeAndNil(TPanel(fieldByName('Panel'))); // jumps to 'First' statement
               // or TPanel(fieldByName('Panel')).free;
            except
               showmessage('ddddddddddddddddd'); // never reaches here
            end;
            next;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

If this isn't the right way to free the panels, what can I do?

Comment: You should not Free the field, but the result of its `AsInteger` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@UweRaabe said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76855034/freeing-runtime-created-components-with-delphi/76855803#comment135490209_76855034), you are freeing the `TField` that is returned by `FieldByName()`, rather than freeing the `TPanel` that is stored in the field's data.

You need to change this statement:

```
freeAndNil(TPanel(fieldByName('Panel')));
```

to this instead:

```
freeAndNil(TPanel(fieldByName('Panel').AsInteger));
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively:

```
TPanel(fieldByName('Panel').AsInteger).Free;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Another option would be to simply not destroy the `TPanel` objects manually at all. Create each `TPanel` with an `Owner` specified, and let the `Owner` destroy the objects for you, either when it itself is destroyed, or when you call its public `DestroyComponents()` method.

For example, since `TFDmemTable` is a `TComponent` descendant, it can act as the `Owner` (or you can use any other `TComponent` you want), eg:

```
Pictures.FieldByName('Panel').AsInteger := Integer(TPanel.Create(Pictures));

...

procedure TDataForm.PicturesBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Pictures.DestroyComponents;
  Pictures.First;
  while not Pictures.EOF do begin
    Pictures.FieldByName('Panel').AsInteger := 0;
    Pictures.Next;
  end;
end;
```

---

That being said, I question why you are storing memory objects in a DB at all, and especially as 32-bit integers. That will only work if your app is compiled as 32-bit, but will break if you ever upgrade your app to 64-bit. You really should store your objects in a more appropriate container, such as a `TObjectList`.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Your suggestion worked. I store MemTables in files not in a DB. Must I save the Panel's address as 64bit integer to cover the 64bit case ?

Comment: Yes, object pointers are larger in a 64bit process and will need a 64bit integer